# MongoDB Java driver aggregate String

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am getting a String with the structure of JSONArray `[ { "abc" : "123" }, { "def" : "456" } ]`which I need to use to call `mongoCollection.aggregate(theString);`

The aggregate function takes  `List<? extends Bson>` and I am not sure what is the best way to convert the String to `List<? extends Bson>`.

For find() method which takes `Bson var1` I am just converting the String to Document using `Document.parse(theString);`

I am using mongodb 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with this but it looks a little ugly.

```
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(theString);
        List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object jsonObject : jsonArray){
            Document document = Document.parse(jsonObject.toString());
            list.add(document);
        }
        collection.aggregate(list);
```